# How long are password reset links valid for Firebase auth?

Tags: firebase-authentication

The title says it all. I tried to find this information in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email), but it is not stated there. I read somewhere that the links are valid for 2 to 3 hours. But I would like to know the official duration of the validity.

Answer (score 3):

The duration of password reset links is of 1 hour. According to this post in Github. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1884

Comment: Can you also post a link to the resource where you get the info?

Comment: I also want to know the official time of reset link please

Comment: They don't publish the expiration times. They said it **about** 1 hour.